# Как сгенерировать и задать карту высот для Terrain(Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

возник вопрос, как задать карту высот и собственно как ее сгенерировать для terrain.

У меня стоит задача сделать воксельный terrain. И я подумал, что если можно задавать координаты на terrain и давать им значения, то можно тем самым придать ему воксельный вид.

Я не так давно занимаюсь в юнити, так что извиняюсь за свою не компетентность заранее) Буду благодарен любой помощи)

Comment: На форуме мазершипа Юнити есть отдельный туториал на эту тему. Пожалуйста https://forum.unity.com/threads/tutorial-procedural-meshes-and-voxel-terrain-c.198651/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/tutorial-procedural-meshes-and-voxel-terrain-c.198651/ - эти уроки очень помогли в решении проблемы.